# Best practices for persisting ListView columns layout in WPF

Tags: wpf, listview, layout

The goal is to let the user to hide/show/move/resize columns, to save this layout, and to be able to restore it when the app re-starts.
I'll tell you first how I do it. On GridView.Columns, I attach to CollectionChanged, as well as to each Column.With dependency property. When any of the events is fired, I save the order, visibility and widths of the Columns to a proprietary string which I save to an XML settings file.
But it seems to me that this is a quite a bit of manual work - are there popular existing components or practices for saving the Columns layout?

Comment: Yes I know this is an old post.  But see this (also old) article for _a_ solution. http://www.wpfsharp.com/2012/04/10/saving-the-gridview-column-order-in-wpf/ Basically, declare helper classes for the information you want to save, mark them Serializable, use an XmlSerializer to punch them in and out of a convenient file.

Answer (score 2):

Could you save the columns in XAML?  After a quick test it seemed to save the relevant information.  I started with this:

```
<GridView>
    <GridView.Columns>
        <GridViewColumn Header="First Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FirstName}"/>
        <GridViewColumn Header="Last Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding LastName}"/>
        <GridViewColumn Header="Age" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Age}"/>
    </GridView.Columns>
</GridView>
```

And after resizing and moving a few, I called [`XamlWriter.Save`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.xamlwriter.save.aspx) on `GridView.Columns` and got this:

```
<GridViewColumnCollection xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
    <GridViewColumn Width="108.51" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=FirstName}">First Name</GridViewColumn>
    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Age}">Age</GridViewColumn>
    <GridViewColumn Width="83.8533333333333" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=LastName}">Last Name</GridViewColumn>
</GridViewColumnCollection>
```

Comment: This is a good answer - my only reservation would be that when trying to restore, it would override your bindings and captions.

Comment: You are correct.  If you're only looking to store a few key properties I think your existing string method is fine.  Saving the columns as XAML is kind of a nuclear option.